# Is exist on multiple table django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have five models,

```
Model1 - Primary Model
Model2 - One to One with model1
Model3 - One to Many with model1
Model4 - One to One with model1
Model5 - One to Many with model1
```

I need to check if any data exist on each of the table, I can do that by one query each but wanted to know if there is any elegant way of checking if record exist ?

Above is for django

Comment: `One to One with mode1` what `model`? Model1? Model3?

Comment: You can select related objects in the same query with `select_related`

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: sorry its a type, everything connects to model1 @NielGodfreyPonciano

Comment: I belive select_related wont work for backward relation @jkoestinger

Comment: What code to show ? @Martins

Comment: @sixovov947 correct, for those you can use prefetch_related instead, which will trigger an extra query. It can still save you quite a few hits if you're making your check on multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your relationships correctly, then for each instance of `Model1` there could be 1 or more instances in the other models.

If your database is using integrity checks (Foreignkeys, like any normal relational database), then if there is no instance for `Model1`, then you don't even need to look in the other models/tables for instances (you save 4 extra queries in this case).

If the instance exists in `Model1`, then you need to query the other models/tables. If you only need the count, then you can use annotations, maybe like this:

```
from django.db import models

qs = Model1.objects.annotate(
    model2_count=models.Count('model2'),
    model3_count=models.Count('model3'),
    model4_count=models.Count('model4'),
    model5_count=models.Count('model5'))
for e in qs:
    print(e.pk, e.model2_count)
```